# Set property with obsolete attribute in Entity framework databse first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Do anyone know how this is done ?

Eg. Data annotations is checked runtime, I want to run the check compile-time.

Comment: Can you be more especific ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried to create a new class and using [MetadataType(typeof(MYCLASS))] but this does not help.

Comment: Do you get an error ?

Comment: Nope, but i was hoping to get compile errors where the property is used

Comment: Can you show your class and where you want to use?